# Function overloading with default signature

Tags: typescript

I have a function `myFunction` that accepts two parameters:

- `key` of type `"mode" | "foo" | "bar"`
- `value` of type `any`. However, if `key` is `"mode"`, the value must be of type `Mode`

I tried to implement it with function overloading, but it didn't work. I wanted to have one signature for `key` equal `"mode"` and a "fallback" signature for everything else.

```js
export const KEYS = Object.freeze({   
  mode: "mode",
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar",
});
export type Key = (typeof KEYS)[keyof typeof KEYS];

export const MODES = Object.freeze({
  TABLE: "table",
  CARDS: "cards",
});
export type Mode = (typeof MODES)[keyof typeof MODES];

function myFunction(
  key: "mode",
  value: Mode
): void;
function myFunction(key: Key, value: any): void {
    console.log(key, value)
}

myFunction("mode", "cards"); // OK
myFunction("foo", 123); // Argument of type '"foo"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"mode"'.
myFunction("bar", "test"); // Argument of type '"bar"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"mode"'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=104&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wNIFECaBlOAXjgHkAjAK2ARgDoAzKYYAL2AAoBvOHgKB4C2EACbAAXHABEQ0ZIA0-OPQgQJk5RHmKyAQyhrdULQF8AlAG5eoSLDgwAnmGBwMwe0TjsHTiPRe48UwBtAGs3XztHYAjsfABdSytwaHgkNHgAWRIAESwCYnIqGgYmVg5ORQAVAEEAIQAZLDUYHTIAG2AtHgBhaoAlbLw1BD1hVBMLJJt4b2cMkWdiLyiIrNzA0PC-WdWcvITeXnoAV2QaAEsUOAF7ADFTi5R2RTD7NRlOhR4ANx024-EcHmol4pgk3wg52ElhOZxgl2Q1zuD3hT1eElc9jkcF+-0BOmQ9jBOMhwjgFR4PDSqAgHVobQgAHN2K9sbiAaZeMZDjd7nCEexpAt5FIRlAxpILHAAPTS0gYXi8lEC9QqEUARgATABmKWyuDVKCM44CYDIeARWZwADkqs01rg51QcGQEHgOlQqHOjOQrQ6dggcDAeh0ppgwCgcEtURtQtk1toiuR-KekkMIsk4fQkvMMrlhuNpvNUe2Mdt6YdTpdbrgHq9Pr9zhggeDUFDwHDkejTljH0kCaAA)

Why doesn't it work? Do I have to write more explicit signatures for each case?

Comment: You only have one overload, the implementation signature doesn't count. Read [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

Comment: [Relevant doc link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature)

Comment: Thank you for the links. Do you have any implementation suggestions?

Comment: As implied by the docs you could add the missing call signature like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRj2xw). Does that fully address the question or are we missing something?

Comment: @jcalz it fully addresses my question. Thank you.

Comment: @jcalz actually, not really. `myFunction("mode", "THIS SHOULD FAIL")` should fail, but it doesn't. But `Exclude<Key, "mode">` should solve the problem 

Comment: If you have an unmet use case you should [edit] it into the question.  And then feel free to post your own answer including `Exclude<Key, "mode">` since that's the way I'd go for that use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jcalz pointed out, I'm confusing overload signatures with the implementation signature ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature)).

So I specified the desired "fallback" signature separately from the implementation signature:
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wNIFECaBlOAXjgHkAjAK2ARgDoAzKYYAL2AAoBvAKDjgFsIAE2AAuOACJBIiQBpecehAjiJSiHIVkAhlFU6omgL4BKANzdQkWHBgBPMMDgZgdonHb3HEes9x4TAG0Aa1cfWwdgcOx8AF0LS3BoeCQ0eABZEgARLAJicioaBiZWDh4+ABUAQQAhABksVRhtMgAbYE0+AGEqgCUsvFUEXSFUY3NE63gvJ3ThJ2JPSPDMnICQsN8Zlezc+O5uAHpDxG1W1rhUAEsAc2RtGABXJlRuekfkGiuUATsAMQ+XxQ7FCdlU0g6sjgADczo8xHA5iITOJoRArkILO9PjBvshfgCcXiQa5xFgQAhWo8RAAeFx2KFSeYSAB8UNhVIR2mQdhRMPRmLgxzgADkIDAnOTKdTgDSWQdhVd+GBWm9Abifvx-uriaDxPT2XCuTy+WiMXByogUKgIO1aK0IDcSQyYUaTNwjActYSgch2EyZIzhlBRhJzEKTiQMNxvTrgQHIZJUAALCCPVpCRTaK6tMNmCNwQC8G4BZHdFEDgEGhwCgDu0mf4DwQyeAqFsyaureG51oMe1RPj6jkcAAjAAmADM4eFUd7Po1fokBiHEgl6DzBajQA)

```js
export const KEYS = Object.freeze({
  mode: "mode",
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar",
});
export type Key = (typeof KEYS)[keyof typeof KEYS];

export const MODES = Object.freeze({
  TABLE: "table",
  CARDS: "cards",
});
export type Mode = (typeof MODES)[keyof typeof MODES];

// call signatures
function myFunction(key: "mode", value: Mode): void;
function myFunction(key: Exclude<Key, "mode">, value: any): void; // Note Exclude<>

// impl
function myFunction(key: Key, value: any): void {
  console.log(key, value)
}

myFunction("mode", "cards"); // OK
myFunction("mode", "should fail"); //  No overload matches this call.
myFunction("foo", 123); // OK
myFunction("bar", "test"); // OK
```

Note `Exclude<Key, "mode">`. Without it `myFunction("mode", "should fail")` will not throw an error.